# How do I determine which set number from a poly bag

Tags: set-identification

I have a poly bag. It is number two in a set. Underneath the number is 342R7. The set is from 2015. The primary colors are burnt red, yellow, and gray.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE.  The long numbers on the bag are the part number of the bag itself and don't help here.  The year narrows it down, but not enough.  *We can't help much without clear pictures of the bag.*  But with a picture the folks here can probably find it.

Comment: The year on the bag concerns the copyright of *the bag*, and has nothing to do with the set - and the set Joost determined this to be is indeed not from 2015.

Answer (score 7):

This bag is from [60150-1: Pizza Van](https://brickset.com/sets/60150-1/Pizza-Van)

[image]

Based on:

- [6015347: Plate 3X3](https://brickset.com/parts/6015347/plate-3x3) in Medium Stone Grey
- [4618986: Plate 2X6](https://brickset.com/parts/4618986/plate-2x6) in New Dark Red
- And the yellow parts

According the instructions bag two is for the van

Comment: This is amazing! I can’t believe you figured this out! I am grateful!